# Range validation in Wicket when using TextField<Integer>

Tags: java, wicket, textfield, rangevalidator

I have `TextField<Integer>` and i want to validate that the input contain exactly 8 digit. if it was `TextField<String>` i would simply add a `PatternValidator("(\\d){8}")` to it but `PatterValidator` extends IValidator and I cant add it to `TextField<Integer>`

how can i validate this textField. i need to use `TextField<Integer>` because this component automatically convert all numbers in UTF8 to Integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a [RangeValidator](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/validation/validator/RangeValidator.html) and set range you are looking for. It shouldn't change html and will validate on form submit.

```
RangeValidator.range(10000000, 99999999);
```